# Why would JOCL CL.clEnqueueReadBuffer never return?

Tags: opencl, jocl

Currently I have a kernel that is supposed to take a flattened array of bytes and transform render some image, I have all of this implemented, however, I have a line of code that never returns

```
ret = CL.clEnqueueReadBuffer(this.commandQueue, this.finalImageBuffer, CL.CL_TRUE, 0, this.outputSize, Pointer.to(this.outArray), 0, null, null);
```

why would it never return, that's my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have it set as a blocking read. If you set it to CL.CL_FALSE, does it return?

Comment: Hello Simon, it does return, as it should, however, I need a blocking call, because I need a fully rendered image output.

Comment: Why would such a call get stuck in an infinite loop, if I could get the reason, I could debug much more consciously.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change it back of course. It sounds like it's waiting for some previous command in the command queue to finish then. Your problem might be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Simon, that seems to be the issue, calling ```CL.clFinish()``` seems to get stuck when I call it before my reading call. Will start tracing that lead and see where it goes, thanks